# Java: Print first, fourth, seventh... of an array using only ONE LOOP?

Tags: java, loops

Given an array of integer.

I want to first print print 1st, 4th, 7th.. numbers.
Then 2nd, 5th, 8th.. 
And then 3rd, 6th, 9th..

I want to use ONLY ONE LOOP to iterate through the array. How can I do this?

(Note: Size of array will always be like 4, 7, 10, 13.. and so on, i.e. in increments of 3.)

Thanks.

Comment: While it's definitely feasible, it's going to be pretty painful to read. A nested loop would be a lot simpler. *Why* do you only want one loop? Will there always be exactly 9 integers?

Comment: Jon: The length of array will be like 4, 7, 10, 13... i.e. increments of 3. The problem I am dealing with uses only one loop, I don't want to alter that.

Comment: Jon: Just curious; how can I accomplish this with nested loop?

Answer (score 2):

Write a function

```
private int index(int i, int length)
```

which computes the right index for the loop variable i

**EDIT**

Wasn't that easy as i first thought:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 };
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        System.out.println(array[index(i, array.length)]);
    }
}

private static int index(int i, int length) {

    int third = (length + 2) / 3;
    if (length % 3 == 1 && i >= third) { // spezial, because second third is smaller
        return index(i - 1, length - 1);

    }

    int group = i % third;

    return (group) * 3 + (i / third);
}
```

**EDIT**
did some cleanup;

Comment: Can you please be more elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a rough guess but something like this should work-

```
int b[]; int temp=b.length;//Store the inputted numbers in this array
for(int i=0, j=0; j<3; i=i+3){
    if(i<temp) System.out.println(b[i]);
    if(i>=temp){
        i=i%3+1;
        ++j;
     }


    }
```

Comment: This is a more generalized form for a variable sized array

Answer (score 1):

Here's how i would do this,print each array sequence vertically:-

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int k = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i += k) {
        System.out.print(a[i] + "\t");
        if (i + 1 < a.length) {
            System.out.print(a[i + 1] + "\t");
            if (i + 2 < a.length) {
                System.out.println(a[i + 2]);
            }
        }
    }
```

OUTPUT

1   2   3

4   5   6

7   8   9

10

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the loop index again when length is reached. Check the code below

```
int a[] = {4,6,7,2,7,8,9,4,3};
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int start = 3;
int printed = 0;
while (i < a.length && printed < a.length) {
 printed++;
 System.out.print(a[i] + " ");

 i += start;
 if (!(i < a.length)) {
  i = ++j;
  System.out.println();
 }
}
```

Output

```
4 2 9 
6 7 4 
7 8 3
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/MRqizq)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the length of the array is 9, which is how I read the second line in the question, this would be my approach:

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

for (int i = 0; i < a.length*3; i+=3) {
    System.out.print(a[i%a.length + i/a.length] + " ");
}
```

Output:

```
1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9
```